# Inputs to the nn.MultiheadAttention?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, attention-model

I have `n`-vectors which need to be influenced by each other and output `n` vectors with same dimensionality `d`. I believe this is what `torch.nn.MultiheadAttention` does. But the forward function [expects](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.MultiheadAttention.html) query, key and value as inputs. According to [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/illustrated-self-attention-2d627e33b20a#8481) blog, I need to initialize a random weight matrix of shape `(d x d)` for each of `q`, `k` and `v` and multiply each of my vectors with these weight matrices and get 3 `(n x d)` matrices. Now are the `q`, `k` and `v` expected by `torch.nn.MultiheadAttention` just these three matrices or do I have it mistaken?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you want to use self attention, just pass your input vector into `torch.nn.MultiheadAttention` for the query, key and value.

```
attention  = torch.nn.MultiheadAttention(<input-size>, <num-heads>)

x, _ = attention(x, x, x)
```

The pytorch class returns the output states (same shape as input) and the weights used in the attention process.

Comment: Are the inputs `x` supposed to be sequences of token ids or embeddings?

Comment: x is the embeddings

Comment: this also assumes the k,q,v-dimensions are the same

Comment: Slightly cleaner: `x = attention(x, x, x, need_weights=False)`